# why keypress is not working in mat-select?

Tags: angular

I want to execute function in typescript on any key pressing by user. For example, if the drop down contains values like 'Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Mango' and if user press 'M', focus should be get to the 'Mango' as per the standard HTML behaviour. Standard HTML behaviour for  is : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select

I have added (keypress) to the mat-select in html code. But it seems that keypress is not working as code in typescript function is not getting executed.
Angular version is 4.

below is the angular code:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select (keypress)="selectKeyPress($event)" placeholder="State" formControlName = "state" required id="stateDrop">
        <ng-container *ngFor = "let item of stateList">
            <mat-option [value] = "item.stateId">{{item.name}}</mat-option> 
        </ng-container>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf="(form.controls['state'].invalid && form.controls['state'].touched)">You must select a state.</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Could you provide please a stackblitz, coz it seems working for me.

Comment: [The default example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/rlqnpbbojamm?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.ts) is working. Please provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Comment: keypress wasn't working for me, but keydown worked, so I used that instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this its work for me

```
angular.element(document).find('input').on('keydown', function (ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

if above code is not work use this code in input

```
ng-keydown="$event.stopPropagation()"
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the case that it was working out of the box on some elements and on some not. So actually it is default behaviour of the mat-selects.
But in our case, the Material Theming sometimes overwrote the injected styling from the MatSelectModule and in some cases vice versa which caused the font-size sometimes to be 14px and sometimes 16px. When it was 16px (from the default Material Theming), it was quite obvious that the calculation of where the option to jump to currently was located was broken, the selection jumped to a point over the actual item. So we overwrote the theming in the end to always use 14px, too (subheading-2 is the config property used in the mat-option-typography mixin). You can try it with the debugger to just overwrite the font-size until the correct element is selected. Here the code to modify the mat option font size:

```
$mat-option-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
  $subheading-2: mat-typography-level(14px, 24px, 500)
);
@include mat-option-typography($mat-option-typography);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had searched on your question but better thing is founded to used autocomplete.
https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

reference link : [Using keyboard to select items in md-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060133/using-keyboard-to-select-items-in-md-select)

Comment: `md` prefixed components are deprecated dude, that would be better a comment than an answer :)

Comment: @selemmn i had given link not exact solution

Comment: @Pradip more reason to be a comment then.